# How to push object value with the same property value to the same subarray in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I'm unsure how to word the title of this question so I hope my explanation will make more sense. I have an array with 190 objects, each containing six keys and values, like this:

[image]

My goal is to create an array that starts with a year, followed by all Values from that year, like this:

```js
[
  [2000,16707,2416,8653,22176,1047,24096,27045,86019,27667,231],
  [2001,18249,2605,8458,22164,1181,24785,26497,85163,28912,316],
  [2002,.....]
  ...
]
```

Right now, this is my code:

```js
var dataNumbers = new Array();

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  if (data[i].Countries == country) {
    dataNumbers.push([data[i].Periods, data[i].Value])
  }
}
```

This results in an array that looks like this:

```js
[
  [2000,16707],
  [2000,2416],
  [2000,8653],
  [2000,22176],
  ...
  ...
]
```

How can I group all numbers that match in my case Periods as shown above?

Comment: do you have some data to test? is the array with the objects sorted? why do you check for `country`?

Comment: I check for country not specifically for this piece of code big for the bigger picture. It makes it so that it only shows the data specific to the country selected.

Answer (score 1):

You could take an object as hash table for grouping the same `Peroids` and get the values of the hash table as result.

```
result = Object.values(data.reduce((r, { Periods, Value }) => {
    r[Periods] = r[Periods] || [Periods];
    r[Periods].push(Value);
    return r;
}, {}));
```

A slightly different approach with a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map).

```
result = Array.from(
    data.reduce((m, { Periods, Value }) => m.set(Periods, [...(m.get(Periods) || []), Value]), new Map),
    (k, v) => [k, ...v]
);
```

Comment: I believe this is exactly what I needed, thank you!